# Adjust bootstrap button height based on amount of text

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass

How can I adjust my button height based on the text? This is different to the other questions asked based on the fact that I am using BootStrap classes and am unaware if this is affecting the result.

I would have thought it would have been something similar to doing this:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 50px;
height: 100px;
word-break: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
```

but none of the above has worked. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="accordion collapsible-views" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id={{collapseCard.headingId}}>
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" attr.data-target="#{{collapseCard.btnTargetId}}" aria-expanded="true" attr.aria-controls={{collapseCard.btnTargetId}}>
          {{collapseCard.btnTitle}}
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.btn {
        width: 100%;
        background: url(/assets/images/drop-down-icon.png) 100% no-repeat;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .card-header {
        border-bottom: 0px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding-left: 12px;
    }

    .card {
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
    }
```

[Button height should be adjusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNjNK.png)

Comment: Hi James, Welcome to the community. I understand you want to change the "height" of the button based upon the text. Does that mean in some instances you want it to be smaller that uses the same "card-header". 

I would recommend adding an additional id or style to the card or button so you can identify it, then style it out like button#myRef{ height: .... }